# Special Double side printing on microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word

normal double sided printing is
The layout below:

```
1 2 per paper  
3 4   
5 6  
7 8
```

but i want to print:

```
1 5 per paper  
2 6  
3 7  
4 8
```

Comment: You can list the pages to be printed in order when you choose to print specific pages.